# Ubuntu 12.04 Lts not booting

Tags: 12.04

I installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS and it was working properly. I didnt use for one month and now when i boot it the screen becomes blank with a cursor blinking on it. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reconfiguring Lightdm can fix your problem**

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> when blank screen appears.
- If `tty1` CLI appears then login with your user name and execute following commands

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  then chose `lightdm` from the list, and restart your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot now
  ```

If this doesn't work then you have to follow following methods.

---

Installing **GDM** (a display manager like lightdm) can fix your problem:

**Method 1:**

- This method works when you are able to go to at least the `command line interface`.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> when your system starts and starts freezing or black screen appears. It will let you to use Command Line Interface. Then login using your username and password, and try following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdm
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm

then selected gdm from the list, and restarted your system:
$ sudo reboot
```

Your system will be restarted with a login screen which will let you to access your system.

**Method 2**: If *1st* didn't work for you then you can try this method. But it would be very long for you:

**Here are the steps how to install using *2nd* method**

- Go to following link and download gdm for Ubuntu 12.04.2 amd64. (chose `ubuntu 
  proposed universe` out of three listed there.)

  http://pkgs.org/download/gdm
- Put the *.deb file just installed to any pendrive.
- Then login in save mode or `Recovery Mode`. After a lot of text displayed in black

  screen one window will come which list some options. First go to option **Grub**, it
  will mount your file system in read/write mode. Then chose **root** option in order
  to login as root. Then go to the pendrive where you saved the deb file. The drive 
  should be listed in in /media. I am assuming that you saved the file in `gdm` 
  directory inside `pendrive` (`pendrive` is the name of your pendrive)

  ```
  # cd /media && ls
  ```

  (which will list your `pendrive` if you don't get `pendrive`
   folder then go to **Mount Pendrive Section** at last, then come back here and continue to next step.)

  ```
  # cd /media/pendrive/gdm
  ```

  (go to gdm directory where .deb file is saved.)

  ```
  # dpkg -i *.deb
  ```

  (installing gdm)
  While installing gdm one window will come which will ask your to chose lightdm or gdm
  from the list. Chose gdm. If this window doesn't appear then try following command:

  ```
  # dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  (chose gdm) Then finally execute following command:

  ```
  # reboot (reboot your system)
  ```

**Mount Pendrive Section**

- Mounting pendrive while working in recovery mode.

Run this command:

```
    # fdisk -l
```

Find your device in the list, it is probably something like `/dev/sdb1`. Then execute other commands one by another:

```
    # mkdir /media/pendrive
```

- Run this command if your pendrive is formatted in FAT/FAT32.

  ```
  # mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/pendrive -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
  ```
- Or this command if your pendrive is formatted in NTFS

  ```
  # mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/pendrive
  ```

Hope it will work for you.. For any further assistance please reply..

Comment: ok thanks.. it worked after reconfiguring lightdm.

Comment: hey.. i did reconfiguration of lightdm and when rebooted i was able to login to ubuntu. but from the next time onwards the same black screen again appears and now even tty1 CLI doesnt appear. Also i tried recovery mode but the same case there also. I tried boot repair , but no use .

Comment: Did you install `gdm` as suggested in `Methods`?

Comment: As said in method one , i can get to cli now. Dont know why. And as in method two i cant login to recovery , it shows the same problem. After grub menu a blank screen with cursor blinking. The screen isnt freezed as whatever i type appears on screen.